# Advent 7105 (Sempron 3000) machine won't boot 15.10 from DVD

Tags: boot, 15.10, dvd

I have an old laptop which doesn't have boot from USB option. I can install 14.04 LTS from DVD.

Burning 15.10 onto DVD always fails as, the machine turns off when I try to install. I know the burn process is correct as I've done it from the 32 bit iso, both on a Windows machine and on my new laptop with the same result.

It's the same process as I used for 14.04 and I've also tested the "try without installing" option on the 15.10 boot from DVD. I've also tested the file system integrity and Checking ./casper/filesystem.squashfs came back successfully.

If I try to install or try without installing, the machine just turns off after much clacking of the DVD drive.
It has a Sempron processor (model 3000 I think)

I'm going back to reinstall 14.04 LTS from DVD which I know works but I am very curious to know why it just won't take 15.10 from DVD, which is the only boot option I have.